# Xamarin build fails inside a windows docker container (_ComputeAndroidResourcePaths fails)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a win docker container with visual studio 2019 and xamarin components installed.
When I run **"msbuild my-solution.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release" /p:AndroidSdkDirectory="C:\Android"** I get the following error:

```
    "_ComputeAndroidResourcePaths:
  Creating directory "obj\Release\100\res\".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\obj\Release\100\lp\
0\jl\__res_name_case_map.txt'. [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.cspro
j]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KD
I.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ExtractAll(ZipArchive zip, String destination, Action`2 progressCallback, Func`2 modifyCa
llback, Func`2 deleteCallback, Func`2 skipCallback) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(IDictionary`2 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirector
ies, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments) [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.RunTask() [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1107,2): error X
ARLP7023:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() [C:\KDI\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj]
```

I checked the path and seems the __res_name_case_map.txt is missing.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
 # escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.8.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]


# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
#ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/befdb1f9-8676-4693-b031-65ee44835915/c541feeaa77b97681f7693fc5bed2ff82b331b168c678af1a95bdb1138a99802/vs_Community.exe C:\TEMP\vs2019.exe

RUN C:\TEMP\vs2019.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --includeRecommended --includeOptional`
   --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0
  

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Comment: It is a generated file though. Not sure why it would be missing.

Comment: @Cheesebaron the problem was that I mapped the project folder (via docker run -v) and Visual Studio? from my machine was preventing some folder/files to create/delete inside contianer. I didn't spot anything in the logs, but I suspected this and tried to COPY in dockerfile and now it's working. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Just add an answer yourself and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was mapping the project folder during container startup (docker run -v project:/project) and perhaps Visual Studio from my machine was preventing those files to be created during build process. Now I COPY inside the dockerfile and works. However, the image will be used as a base image in gitlab CI and the code will be automatically added.